# Toggle class in vanilla JS is not working

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to create a vanilla JS to do app. Users can input todo item(s) and click on them to mark 'em complete. But for some reason the "complete" class is toggling. It toggles on *li* items that are present previously but not on newly created *li*

```js
const li = document.querySelectorAll('li');
const btn = document.querySelector('button');
var list = document.getElementById('container');
const inputTxt = document.querySelector('input');
const val = document.getElementById('item');



//add todo function
function btnClick() {
  var inputText = inputTxt.value;
  var entry = document.createElement('li');
  entry.className = "incomplete";
  entry.appendChild(document.createTextNode(inputText));
  list.appendChild(entry);
}

function ToggleClass(event) {
  var check = event.target;
  var find = check.closest('li');
  this.classList.toggle('complete');
  console.log(find);
}


btn.addEventListener('click', btnClick);
li.forEach(item => item.addEventListener('click', ToggleClass));
```

```css
.todo {
  text-align: center;
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
}

.complete {
  color: green;
}

li:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.complete {
  position: relative;
}

.complete:before {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  left: 0;
  top: 50%;
  right: 0;
  border-top: 1px solid;
  border-color: inherit;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-5deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(-5deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(-5deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(-5deg);
  transform: rotate(-5deg);
}
```

```html
<body>

  <section class="todo">
    <div class="wrap">
      <input type="text" name="todo_text" id="item">
      <button>Add item</button>
      <ul id="container">
        <li class="todo_item complete">Some todo item text</li>
        <li class="todo_item complete">Some todo item text</li>
        <li class="todo_item incomplete">Some todo item text</li>

      </ul>
    </div>
  </section>
```

My guess, May be it has to do something with creating the textNode.

Comment: The problem is how you addEventListener (only to existing items). You can add it to the container, and check the event.target instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use event delegation on the `ul` instead (at the moment, your listeners are on each button instead, but you're not adding new listeners when items are added):

```js
const li = document.querySelectorAll('li');
const btn = document.querySelector('button');
var list = document.getElementById('container');
const inputTxt = document.querySelector('input');
const val = document.getElementById('item');

list.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
  const { target } = e;
  if (target.tagName !== 'LI') return;
  target.classList.toggle('complete');
});

//add todo function
function btnClick() {
  var inputText = inputTxt.value;
  var entry = document.createElement('li');
  entry.className = "incomplete";
  entry.appendChild(document.createTextNode(inputText));
  list.appendChild(entry);
}

btn.addEventListener('click', btnClick);
```

```css
.todo {
  text-align: center;
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
}

.complete {
  color: green;
}

li:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.complete {
  position: relative;
}

.complete:before {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  left: 0;
  top: 50%;
  right: 0;
  border-top: 1px solid;
  border-color: inherit;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-5deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(-5deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(-5deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(-5deg);
  transform: rotate(-5deg);
}
```

```html
<body>

  <section class="todo">
    <div class="wrap">
      <input type="text" name="todo_text" id="item">
      <button>Add item</button>
      <ul id="container">
        <li class="todo_item complete">Some todo item text</li>
        <li class="todo_item complete">Some todo item text</li>
        <li class="todo_item incomplete">Some todo item text</li>

      </ul>
    </div>
  </section>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the event listener to newly created elements inside the `btnClick()` function, otherwise the new elements won't have the listener.

So:

```
function btnClick() {
  var inputText = inputTxt.value;
  var entry = document.createElement('li');
  entry.className = "incomplete";
  entry.addEventListener('click', ToggleClass);
  entry.appendChild(document.createTextNode(inputText));
  list.appendChild(entry);
}
```